# $y\in l_\infty$, $U$ defined on $l_1$ by $(Ua)(x)=\sum_n a_ny_nx^n$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $a\in l_1$. Show that $\lVert U\rVert=\lVert y\rVert$.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

> Let $y=(y_n)\in l_\infty$. Define $U:l_1\to C[0,1]$ by $(Ua)(x)=\sum_n a_ny_nx^n, \forall x\in [0,1], \forall a=(a_n)\in l_1$. Show that $\lVert U\rVert=\lVert y\rVert$.

I proved $\lVert(Ua)(x)\rVert\leq \lVert y\rVert\cdot\lVert a\rVert$ and I am trying to find an $a\in l_1$ such that $\lVert(Ua)(x)\rVert=\lVert y\rVert\cdot\lVert a\rVert$ but could not find. Here $ C[0,1]$ is equipped with sup. norm.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is possible that an operator between Banach spaces will not attain its norm, so your try might turn out to be futile.

To prove that the norm of $U$ equals $|\!|y|\!|_{\infty}$, assume w.l.o.g
that $|\!|y|\!|_{\infty}=1$, and consider the case where there is some $n$ such that $|y_n|=1$. In this case you can choose $a=e_n$  (the vector having $1$ in the $n$'th place and zeros otherwise) and you see that $|\!|Ua|\!|=1$. In the general case there need not be any $n$ such that $|y_n|=1$, but for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find some $n$ for which $|y_n|>1-\varepsilon$, and so taking $a=e_n$ you find that the norm of $Ua$
is at least $1-\varepsilon$, and since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, the conclusion follows.

Comment: You can use `\lVert y\rVert` to get $\lVert y \rVert.$ It's much easier to work with in general, and quicker to render.

Comment: Thank you! I've been using |\!| to get the two verticals closer to each other up till now....

Comment: So I gathered. If you had to do something like $$\left\lVert\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}A^n\right\rVert,$$ though, your way would be rather a pain, whereas the other way is just ´\left\lVert\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}A^n\right\rVert´.

Comment: If we're talking LaTeX here, I'll say that `\|y\|` is easier to type, with the same effect: $\|y\|$ vs $\lVert y \rVert$... @CameronBuie

Comment: @Michelle: Even better! Thank you!